# 'Sum' function returning TRUE or FALSE values instead of numeric?

Tags: r

I am attempting to creating a frequency  table based off of the following data.

```
> order_x
# A tibble: 16 x 5 
   Order_ID Product           Price Quantity total
      <int> <chr>             <dbl>    <int> <dbl>
 1     4299 Vegetarian Pizza   11.0        2  22.0
 2     4299 Hawaiian Pizza     12.0        3  35.8
 3     4299 Meatlovers Pizza   14.0        1  14.0
 4     1209 Margherita Pizza   11.0        2  22.0
 5     3899 Meatlovers Pizza   14.0        1  14.0
 6     2780 Seafood Pizza      14.0        2  28.0
 7     2780 Pepperoni Pizza    13.0        1  13.0
 8     2780 BBQ Chicken Pizza  15.0        3  44.8
 9     2780 Vegetarian Pizza   11.0        1  11.0
```

The code to get the "Frequency" column is the following.

```
table$Frequency <- sum(as.numeric(order_x$Quantity[order_x$Product == table$Pizza]))
```

And it returns this (which is where I'm stuck).

```
> table
               Pizza Frequency 
1:  Meatlovers Pizza      TRUE         
2:     Supreme Pizza      TRUE         
3: BBQ Chicken Pizza      TRUE         
4:     Seafood Pizza      TRUE         
5:  Vegetarian Pizza      TRUE         
6:  Margherita Pizza      TRUE         
7:    Hawaiian Pizza      TRUE        
8:   Pepperoni Pizza      TRUE
```

Instead of 'TRUE' I'd like it to be the sum of the Quantity values of each category of Product.

Cheers.

Comment: The definition of the input `table` is missing.

Comment: So many ways. Using `by`, `tapply`, `aggregate`, then there's dplyr (group_by %>% summarise),... so many answers to this question in here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Edward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7514527/edward) who said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358830/sum-function-returning-true-or-false-values-instead-of-numeric/60358992#comment106772841_60358830):

> So many ways. Using `by`, `tapply`, `aggregate`, then there's dplyr (group_by %>% summarise),... so many answers to this question in here.

I completely forgot about the capabilities of dyplyr group_by here. Used that and it worked completely fine.

Comment: The was no answer to accept.